# Sentencia IF en xsl

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

me encuentro realizando una sentencia if cuando el dato viene vació.

este el el documento XML
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<document>
<fields>
    <field id="HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD" type="STGString">Avenida maximo 1918</field>
    <field id="HCR_S2_1_COMUNA" type="STGString">RENCA</field>
    <field id="HCR_S2_1_BODEGA" type="STGString">NO</field>
    <field id="HCR_S2_1_TIPO" type="STGString">NO</field>
</fields>
</document>
```

`

y lo que quiero generar es un IF que cuando el campo HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD no contenga datos, no se ejecute la sentencia. Esto lo estaba realizando de esta manera.

```
    <xsl:if test="field[@id='HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD'] != ''">
    <HCR_S2_1>
            <HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document/fields/field[@id='HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD']/text()"/>
            </HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD>
            <HCR_S2_1_COMUNA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document/fields/field[@id='HCR_S2_1_COMUNA']/text()"/>
                </HCR_S2_1_COMUNA>
                <HCR_S2_1_BODEGA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document/fields/field[@id='HCR_S2_1_BODEGA>']/text()"/>
                </HCR_S2_1_BODEGA>
                <HCR_S2_1_TIPO> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="document/fields/field[@id='HCR_S2_1_TIPO']/text()"/>
                </HCR_S2_1_TIPO>
        </HCR_S2_1>
    </xsl:if>
```

hasta el momento sin resultado con

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta que he encontrado

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="categoryName and string-length(categoryName) &gt; 0">
    <xsl:value-of select="categoryName " />
</xsl:when>
```

y codigo queda asi

```
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length(document/fields/field[@id='HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD'])&gt; 0">
        <HCR_S2_1>
                <HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document/fields/field[@id='HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD']/text()"/>
                </HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD>
                <HCR_S2_1_COMUNA>
                    <xsl:value-of select="document/fields/field[@id='HCR_S2_1_COMUNA']/text()"/>
                </HCR_S2_1_COMUNA>

        </HCR_S2_1> 
        </xsl:when>

        </xsl:choose>
```

[Check if a string is null or empty in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825831/check-if-a-string-is-null-or-empty-in-xslt)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con when: (para respuesta = null)

`<xsl:when test="not(string(field[@id='HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD']))">`

Si hablamos de recibir una cadena vacía:

`<xsl: when test = "string-length (field[@id='HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD']) <1">`

(Acuérdate de cerrar el when)

Comment: hola sergio, probe con las sentencias que escribiste pero sin resultado... crees que pueda ser usando /text()? ya que esto es lo que rescata el texto del XML

Comment: mi idea es: Si el campo HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD contiene datos, se despliega la lista.

Comment: Sí, pero text() no parece ser el error. En un validador, es el if el que da este error: `Not well formed: The prefix "xsl" for element "xsl:if" is not bound.`

Comment: me lanza error con when, probe cambiandolo a if. funciona pero si el dato HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD viene vació igual ejecuta la sentencia y muestra la lista(los demás campos) cosa que no debería hacer

Comment: los error que me han salido eran debido a que antes del when, se tiene que abrir una etiqueta choose... con esto funciona,... pero al momento de que el campo HCR_S2_1_DIRECCION_PROPIEDAD  del XML viene pero sin datos, esto igual genera la sentencia y muestra los campos

Comment: Gracias estimado, me ayudo a encontrar la respuesta !

Comment: Me alegro! Saludos